Blazor Web App project EditForm not calling handler
This is the Contact component of my Blazor WebApp project in Dotnet 8.
The MailSender is a service outside the component. The problem is that when I click the Send button, it does not hit the 'CallForm' method, instead it gives me a blank page with this message: 'A valid antiforgery token was not provided with the request. Add an antiforgery token, or disable antiforgery validation for this endpoint.'
When I check the Network activity on the Browser, it made a POST call to localhost and got a BadRequest, but in the payload of the call you can see that the antiforgery token is sent twice:
Payload:
_handler=testForm&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8PrBKUcP_2BApN476NPsIEP8rTXN_zrI4-5nDXMWjirv5ixEAyUkXxxnaXkIwaBbTxESiX9LLr_KiAweW-QhJ4E2DGNYJLBJaLQ__SOz9NIRMR_tl7zCnamZONe7bOcy3e__EaqW4rTDkL-C3VbsFEQ&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8PrBKUcP_2BApN476NPsIEP8rTXN_zrI4-5nDXMWjirv5ixEAyUkXxxnaXkIwaBbTxESiX9LLr_KiAweW-QhJ4E2DGNYJLBJaLQ__SOz9NIRMR_tl7zCnamZONe7bOcy3e__EaqW4rTDkL-C3VbsFEQ
Any idea of what I am doing wrong?
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.Net.Mail;
@using System.Net;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
@using OneManArmyBlazorWeb.Models
@using OneManArmyBlazorWeb.Services
@using OneManArmyBlazorWeb.Settings

@namespace OneManArmyBlazorWeb.Components.Sections

@inject ILogger<Contact> _logger 
@inject IMailSender _mailSender

<!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact" class="contact section">

    <!-- Section Title -->
    <div class="container section-title" data-aos="fade-up">
        <h2>Get in Touch</h2>
        <p>
            Whether you have a question, a project idea, or just want to connect, I’d love to hear from you!
        </p>
    </div><!-- End Section Title -->

    <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">

        <EditForm method="post" Model="Model" OnInvalidSubmit="CallForm" FormName="testForm" Enhance action="" class="php-email-form" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
            @* <DataAnnotationsValidator /> *@
            @* <ValidationSummary /> *@

            <div class="row gy-4">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="name-field" class="pb-2">Your Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name-field" class="form-control" @bind-value="Model.Name">
                    @* <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Name)" /> *@
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="email-field" class="pb-2">Your Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" @bind-value="Model.Email">
                    @* <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Email)" /> *@
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="subject-field" class="pb-2">Subject</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind-value="Model.Subject">
                    @* <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Subject)" /> *@
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="message-field" class="pb-2">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" @bind="Model.Message" rows="10" id="message-field"></textarea>
                    @* <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Message)" /> *@
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                    <div class="error-message @errorShowClass">@errorMessage</div>
                    <div class="sent-message @successShowClass">Your message was sent successfully!</div>

                    <button type="submit" style="@sendButtonBackgroundColor" disabled=@sendButtonDisabled>@sendButtonMessage</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <AntiforgeryToken />
        </EditForm>
        
    </div>

</section>
<!-- /Contact Section -->

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public ContactModel Model { get; set; } = new ();

    public async Task CallForm()
    {
        try
        {
            await _mailSender.SendEmailAsync(Model);

            _logger.LogInformation("Email sent successfully!\nSubject: {Subject}\nName: {Name}\nEmail: {Email}\nMessage: {Message} ", Model.Subject, Model.Name, Model.Email, Model.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("There was an error sending the email: {Error}\nSubject: {Subject}\nName: {Name}\nEmail: {Email}\nMessage: {Message} ",
            e.Message,
            Model.Subject,
            Model.Name,
            Model.Email,
            Model.Message);
        }
    }
}


OnInvalidSubmit="CallForm" is for handling incorrect form state,
you can try using either OnValidSubmit="CallForm" or OnSubmit="CallForm".
You also might need to remove method="post" since you don't intend to submit the values directly to the server via form post.
